# В чем отличие FirebaseInstallations от FirebaseMessaging

Tags: java, android, kotlin, firebase, fcm

FirebaseInstanceId является depreceted. Если открыть официальную документацию от google, то мы можем увидеть следующее:

> Этот класс устарел.
> Идентификатор экземпляра Firebase был заменен на FirebaseInstallations для идентификаторов экземпляров приложения и FirebaseMessaging.getToken () для токенов регистрации FCM.

У меня на проекте используются следующие методы:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId()

FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId.addOnSuccessListener { token ->
                emitter.onSuccess(token.token)
            }
```

Эти методы являются deprected и хотелось бы понять, что именно использовать для того, чтобы их заменить.

Если перейти по ссылке на похожий вопрос и ответ https://stackoverflow.com/a/51129304/6050599
То можно увидеть что в ответе говорят использовать **FirebaseInstallations  или FirebaseMessaging**
Так и непонятно какой из них использовать.

Comment: Если вы используете только токены FCM то используйте FirebaseMessaging.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а как именно я могу узнать какие токены используются? Может быть используется не только FCM

Comment: Ну... Надо код изучать что и куда отправляется, зачем используется etc. 99% вероятности что только FCM. На самом деле ни разу не видел чтобы была нужна другая инфа (из FirebaseInstallations). Но тут уж, конечно, кроме вас никто этого узнать не сможет. Как искать FirebaseInstallations использование - сказать не могу, ни разу не видел что оно кому-то нужно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб парадоксально, но я посмотрел внутрь метода FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId() и увидел там обращение к firebaseInstallations .

В итоге провел эксперимент, заменил все методы из моего вопроса выше на  FirebaseInstallations и всё осталось работать как прежде(пуши приходят всё ок), а если поменять на FirebaseMessaging то напрочь отказывается работать.

Comment: Крайне неожиданно) Но раз работает - хорошо))

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ничего неожиданного :) Выбери из двух вариантов один верный. В ГАИ сложнее вопросы на права :)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я разобрался в вопросе, если интересно можете почитать)

Answer (score 2):

Хотелось бы начать с того, что раньше, когда мы использовали FirebaseInstanceId и вызывали
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId() - то у нас при следующем запуск приложения создавался новый токен в методе `fun onNewToken(token: String)` в FirebaseMessagingService.

Так же хотелось бы процитировать следующую документацию

> После создания идентификатора экземпляра библиотека периодически отправляет информацию о приложении и устройстве, на котором оно работает, в серверную часть Firebase. Чтобы остановить это, см. DeleteInstanceId ().

Но хочу отметить важную особенность, при вызове данного метода синхронизация с FCM не теряется, **пуши продолжают проходить**.

Далее, когда мы переходим на новые сущности такие как FirebaseInstallations и FirebaseMessaging  и используем методы:
`FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().deleteToken() FirebaseInstallations.getInstance().delete()` то метод `override fun onNewToken(token: String)` **перестает вызываться при следующем старте приложения**. И это очень важный момент.

Далее, пройдемся по новым сущностям:
`FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().deleteToken()` используя данный метод мы сообщаем FCM,что больше не хотим иметь с ним связи и после вызова данного метода **пуши перестают приходить.**

`FirebaseInstallations.getInstance().delete()` - используя данный метод, цитирую документацию :

> Вызовите, чтобы удалить эту установку приложения Firebase из серверной части Firebase.

Видимо удаление установки из серверной части Firebase никак не затрагивает работу с FCM.
Пуши продолжают приходить.

В моем кейсе я отказался от логики пересоздания токена ( в depreceted виде `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId()`  т.к токен теперь получатся однократно и onNewToken(token: String) в FirebaseMessagingService невозможно вызвать при перехода на новые сущности. Соответственно работа теперь строится на той логике, что токен формируется однократно при установке приложения(там есть ещё особенности в виде очистки данных и т.д (см.документацию)).

Answer (score -1):

Вы же сами приводите ответ на свой вопрос.

> FirebaseInstallations для идентификаторов экземпляров приложения

`InstanceId` это и есть идентификатор экземпляра приложения

А вот это

> FirebaseMessaging.getToken () для токенов регистрации FCM.

Для случаев старого кода типа

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().token // и т.п.
```